catkin_make error - ros-noetic-catkin-virtualenv
I installed ros-noetic-catkin-virtualenv using the command sudo apt install ros-noetic-catkin-virtualenv. Then I did catkin_make, it started giving me the following error message:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin_virtualenv/cmake/catkin_install_python.cmake:30 (message):
  range_sensor_layer loaded catkin_virtualenv, but never invoked
  'catkin_generate_virtualenv'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros_lecture/externals/navigation_layers/range_sensor_layer/CMakeLists.txt:59 (catkin_install_python)

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated!
I already read them
Cmake error - catkin_virtualenv
Mixing non virtualenv packages with virtualenv packages

According to the README, the build tools supported are catkin-tools, colcon, catkin_make_isolated but not catkin_make.
I suggest you may uninstall ros-noetic-catkin-virtualenv if it is not required in your project. Otherwise, you need to run catkin_make_isolated for your build.
